# jQuery & PHP and MYSQL IE Problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Now All of this code works fine in Firfox but in IE the divs dont change when the php infomation changes.

Can some one help me please as i am working on a project and this is holding me back
Thank you.

Here is the **jQuery Code:**

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#not").css('display','none');
$("#fonline").css('display','none');
$("#not").hide();
$("#fonline").hide();
$("#shfm").click(function () {
$("#not").hide();
$("#fonline").toggle();
});

$("#notifi").click(function () {
$("#fonline").hide();
$("#not").toggle();
});

});

function closeboxes() {
$("#fonline").hide();
$("#not").hide();
}
        function loadContent(id) {
        $("#contentArea").load("notifications.php?o="+id+"");
        };

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#settings").toggle(
function () {
$(this).html('X Close');
},
function () {
$(this).html('Settings');
}
);
});

function FriendsContent(id) {
$("#fArea").load("friends_online.php?fo="+id+"");
};

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Options").toggle(
function () {
$(this).html('X Close');
},

function () {
$(this).html('Options');
}
);
});

var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
$('#fArea').fadeOut("slow").load('response.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000);

**PHP Code:**

$cOption = $_GET['fo'];

```
switch($cOption) {

case 1:
$recordsPerPage = 5; 
$pageNum = 1;

if(isset($_GET['pg'])) {
$pageNum = $_GET['pg'];
settype($pageNum, 'integer');
}

echo "<table width='98%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";

$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $recordsPerPage;

$onlineresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM online") or die (mysql_error()); 
while ($ousers = mysql_fetch_array($onlineresult)) { 
$onuid = $ousers['uid'];


$flist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends_list WHERE fid='$onuid' AND uid='$myid' LIMIT $offset, $recordsPerPage;") or die (mysql_error()); 
while ($fri = mysql_fetch_array($flist)) { 
$id = $fir['id'];
$uid = $fri['uid'];
$fid = $fri['fid'];


$userinfomation = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id='$fid'");
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($userinfomation);
$v_tgid = $userinfo['tgid'];
 echo "
  <tr class='menutxt2'>
    <td width='11%' height='21'><center>
    </center></td>
    <td width='50%'><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onClick=\"javascript:chatWith('$v_tgid')\">$v_tgid</a></td>
    <td width='39%'>View Profile</td>
  </tr>
"; 
}
}

echo "</table>";
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM friends_list;"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Mysql Err. 2');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$numrows = $row['id']; 

$maxPage = ceil($numrows/$recordsPerPage);
$nav = '';
for($page = 1; $page <= $maxPage; $page++)
{
if ($page == $pageNum)
{
$nav .= "<span class='menutxt'>Pages: $page </span>";
}
else
{
$nav .= "";
}
}

if ($pageNum > 1) {

$page = $pageNum - 1;
$prev = "";

$first = "";
}
else {
$prev = '';
$first = '';
}

if ($pageNum < $maxPage) {
$page = $pageNum + 1;
$next = "";

$last = "";
}
else {
$next = '';
$last = '';
}
echo "$first <b>$prev</b> $nav<b> $next</b> $last"; 
            echo "

";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo 'Options';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Whoops, didn\'t understand that option: <i>'.$cOption.'</i>';
    }
```

Comment: could you (or anybody with 'edit' capability) edit this post so it is more readable ?

Comment: I used the code button, but I'm not going to wade through and improve the indenting.

Comment: do you have a live link anywhere?

Comment: I Found out now
Thank you T.Stone you have help me alot it is a caching problem
with this line

$("#fArea").load("friends_online.php?fo="+id+"")
it should be 

    function unique_requestid() {
var timestamp = Number(new Date()).toString();
var random = Math.random() * (Math.random() * 100000 * Math.random() );
var unique = new String();
unique = timestamp + random;
return unique;
}

$("#fArea").load("friends_online.php?fo="+id+"&random=" + unique_requestid());

Comment: if that's the case, you should vote and mark his answer as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE tends to cache ajax requests when you don't want it to. The .load() towards the end of your code is issuing a GET request which IE is probably caching instead of fetching from the server.

- http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/ajax-ie-caching-issues/
- [google search 'ie cache ajax jquery'](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=Fuk&q=ie+caches+ajax+jquery&aq=f&oq=&aqi=)